# How to implement abstract classes in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, overloading

I currently have a software which it's comportment change depending on which operating system it's installed (such as `Windows` or `Linux`).
So I just want to create an object fitting the operating system depending of a static config variable `config.soft.type` (a mere string equal to `"windows"` or `"linux"`).

At program' startup, my class need to synchronize so I put the constructor private and added an `async static synchronize()` method for both classes which will create and return the `OperatingSystem` object for Windows or Linux.

How to properly instantiate a repository for both `Windows` and `Linux` classes with their proper types ?

```
// index.ts
...
const { type }: 'windows' | 'linux' = config.soft;
const software = type === 'windows'
  ? await Windows.synchronize(toto, tata, tutu)
  ? await Linux.synchronize(toto, tata, tutu);
software.down();
aRandomFunction(software);
...
```

I would like to pass `software` (of type `Windows | Linux`) to other function (such as `aRandomFunction()`) and use `OperatingSystem` as type for `software` (because both `Windows` and `Linux` classes come from `OperatingSystem`, but I don't know if I need to explicitely put "basic" functions (shared but overloaded by both classes) in `OperatingSystemInterface`)

My classes / interfaces are defined as follow:

```
// OperatingSystem's Interface,
abstract class OperatingSystemInterface

// The implementation of OperatingSystemInterface, I expect Windows and Linux to have `down()` method defined in OperatingSystem without redeclaring it in their interfaces
         class OperatingSystem                         implements OperatingSystemInterface

// OperatingSystem for Windows, with overloaded methods to fitt Windows's need and some more method / properties specific to Windows's class
         class Windows         extends OperatingSystem implements WindowsInterface

// OperatingSystem for Linux
         class Linux           extends OperatingSystem implements LinuxInterface
```

currently, I'm getting errors, such as:

```
error TS2420: Class 'Windows' incorrectly implements interface 'WindowsInterface'.
  Property 'synchronize' is missing in type 'Windows' but required in type 'WindowsInterface'.

8 export class Windows extends OperatingSystem implements WindowsInterface {
               ~~~~~

  src/services/OperatingSystems/types.ts:70:3
     70   synchronize(
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
     71     client: Client,
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ... 
     74     toto: string
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     75   ): Promise<WindowsInterface>;
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'synchronize' is declared here.
```

**But I did declare it**, is it because the prototype isn't matching ? (In the Interface I declared `synchronize()`'s return type of the *Interface and in the class I return an object of the implemented class itself (Linux instead of LinuxInterface, for example), but should I import `Linux` in `types.ts` to put it as return type in `LinuxInterface`'s `synchronize()` ? it doesn't feel right.

Complete code:

```
// types.ts (where I stored my interfaces)
import { Client } from 'client';
import { Config } from 'config';

export abstract class OperatingSystemInterface {
  abstract readonly client: Client;
  abstract readonly config: Config;

  abstract down(): void;
}

export interface WindowsInterface extends OperatingSystemInterface {
  start(): Promise<void>;
  someWindowsRelatedMethod(): Promise<number>;
  anotherWindowsMethod(path: string, value: number): Promise<void>;
  synchronize(
    protected client: Client,
    protected config: Config,
    toto: string
  ): Promise<WindowsInterface>;
}

export interface LinuxInterface extends OperatingSystemInterface {
  start(): Promise<void>;
  synchronize(
    protected client: Client,
    protected config: Config,
    toto: string
  ): Promise<LinuxInterface>;
}
```

```
// OperatingSystem.ts

// Base class which `Windows` and `Linux` overload methods
export class OperatingSystem implements OperatingSystemInterface {
  public readonly informations: Information[] = [];

  constructor(
    protected client: Client,
    protected config: Config,
    toto: string,
  ) {
    this._toto = toto;
    this.client.subscribe(`${config.message}/toto/tata`);
    this.client.subscribe(`${config.message}/titi`);
  }

  get toto(): string {
    return this._toto;
  }

  down(): void {
    this.client.stop();
  }
}
```

```
// Linux.ts
import { Client } from 'client';
import { Config } from 'config';

export class Linux extends OperatingSystem implements LinuxInterface {

  private constructor(
    protected client: Client,
    protected config: Config,
    toto: string
  ) {
    super(client, config, toto);
  }

  static async synchronize(
    client: Client,
    config: Config,
    toto: string
  ): Promise<Linux> {
    const operatingSystem = new Linux(client, config, toto);
    // here some specific code to Linux
    ...
    return operatingSystem;
  }

  async start(): Promise<void> {
    this.client.on('message', (message: Message) => {
      // some Linux's specific code
    });
  }
}
```

```
// Windows.ts
import { Client } from 'client';
import { Config } from 'config';

export class Windows extends OperatingSystem implements WindowsInterface {
  // it represent the Application's permission over the Windows's API
  private windowsInfo: Config = {
    role: 'Viewer',
    isSuperAdmin: true,
  };

  private constructor(
    protected client: Client,
    protected config: Config,
    toto: string
  ) {
    super(client, config, toto);
  }

  static async synchronize(
    client: Client,
    config: Config,
    toto: string
  ): Promise<Windows> {
    const operatingSystem = new Windows(client, config, toto);
    // here some Windows' specific code
    ...
    return operatingSystem;
  }

  async start(): Promise<void> {
    this.client.on('message', (message: Message) => {
      // some Window's specific code
      this.someWindowsRelatedMethod();
    });
  }

  someWindowsRelatedMethod(): Promise<number> {
    ...
  }

  anotherWindowsMethod(path: string, value: number): Promise<void> {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: `new Windows.synchronize(toto, tata, tutu)` looks wrong, did you mean `await` instead of `new`?

Comment: Why is `OperatingSystemInterface` and `abstract class` instead of an `interface` (as the name suggests)?!

Comment: @Bergi Actually, it was originally an Interface, but it didn't worked so I tried to use an abstract class thinking it would works better :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues I can see:

1. Static members belong to the `class`, not the `interface`

The error message is correct:

```
error TS2420: Class 'Windows' incorrectly implements interface 'WindowsInterface'.
  Property 'synchronize' is missing in type 'Windows' but required in type 'WindowsInterface'.
```

Your `WindowsInterface` interface declares the `synchronize()` method, but you have implemented it on your classes as a static method.

So, from the compiler's point of view, your class is missing the `synchronize()` method and it is giving you that error.

It's not possible to define static members on an interface; static members belong to the class, not the interface.

Given how you're using that function elsewhere, you should remove `synchronize()` from the interface.

---

2. The use of your `synchronize()` functions is incorrect

Your static `synchronize()` functions are already instantiating your classes (i.e. `new`ing them) and returning the new instance.
Basically, it's like you're trying to do `new new Windows(...)`, which is incorrect.

And your `synchronize()` functions are returning a promise - you will need to chain the promise or use `await` to "unwrap" the promise to access the value insude.

```
static async synchronize(
    client: Client,
    config: Config,
    toto: string
): Promise<Windows> {
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ - you're returning a promise here
  
    const operatingSystem = new Windows(client, config, toto);
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^ - you're constructing the instances here
    // here some Windows' specific code
    ...
    return operatingSystem;
}
```

```
// index.ts
...
const { type }: 'windows' | 'linux' = config.soft;
const software = type === 'windows'
  ? new Windows.synchronize(toto, tata, tutu)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^ - this is a `Promise<Windows>`
    // don't use `new` here
    // you'll need to "unwrap" the promise to access the Windows instance
  ? new Linux.synchronize(toto, tata, tutu);
    ^^^^^^^^^ - same error here

// You need to chain the promise or use `await` to access the value inside the `software` promise
software.down();
aRandomFunction(software);
```

If you can use a top-level `await` then this is the simplest version of your code:

```
// index.ts
...
const { type }: 'windows' | 'linux' = config.soft;
const software = type === 'windows'
  ? await Windows.synchronize(toto, tata, tutu)
  ? await Linux.synchronize(toto, tata, tutu);

software.down();
aRandomFunction(software);
```

Comment: Yeah, for the second point it's my bad, I wrote `new` instead of `await` while copy / pasting my code, it's actually `await` like you say.
Thanks a lot !